# ¿Como hacer para que mi servidor Linux que tiene instalado un antivirus, analice las computadoras de una red?

Tags: linux, servidor

Tengo instalado en mi computadora que tiene Ubuntu, el antivirus sophos pero lo que quiero es hacer mi computadora un servidor en el que el antivirus analice las computadoras que se puedan conectar a mi computadora a través de la red, pero no se como hacer esa conexión.

Answer (score 0):

El servidor que tiene el antivirus va a analizar solo lo que tiene dentro de el. Por lo tanto solo analizará los recursos compartidos que exporta a los demás equipos.

Si comparte una carpeta que utilizan todos los equipos, en el momento que alguien copie un fichero con virus lo limpiará.

En entornos corporativos, todos los pcs tienen un antivirus, existe un servidor de firmas dentro de la empresa que se dedica a actualizar a todos los antivirus y centraliza los logs con las alertas.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca lo he hecho, quizás es una tontería, pero, tal vez puedas montar en una carpeta especial, digamos, dentro de Documentos una llamada **lan**, por `sshfs` las raíces de las computadoras conectadas, es decir, estas previamente tienen que permitir ese tipo de conexión y quizás el antivirus lea esas raíces montadas cada una dentro de la carpeta **lan**. Esos puntos de montaje tendrán que estar en el servidor que tiene el antivirus.

Comment: Como tal el antivirus no tiene acceso a un sistema remoto, lo que hice para resolverlo fue instalar un servidor NFS en donde tengo una carpeta compartida que cualquier computadora en la red puede montar y ahí están todos los archivos de configuración para que las computadoras puedan instalar el antivirus desde mi computadora. Como tal hice un servidor de actualización en donde mi computadora puede hacer los cambios que quiera para configurar las computadoras conectadas a la red que tengan instalado el antivirus.

Comment: No es que tenga acceso a un sistema remoto, es que tu ejecutes `sshfs usuario@ipremota:/ carpeta1` por cada ip remota que tengas y luego que el antivirus lea esas carpeta, que en realidad son la raíces de los host remotos después de ejecutar sshfs.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el dato, lo voy a intentar

Comment: Después de montar con `sshfs`, para desmontar ese punto de montaje usa `fusermount -u <carpeta donde montaste la raíz de dispositivo remoto>` o si no te aparecerán intimidantes mensajes de que no puedes listar los contenidos de esa carpeta.